# Logcat not showing errors

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I have looked through many different solutions for this problem but I cannot find one that is working for me.

My logcat has randomly stopped working properly. It seems like it has some filters set on it, but I have made sure that no filters is on and that it is looking for errors in my project. My app will crash but nothing relevant will appear in the Logcat.

I have not messed with the Gradle at all so I really don't know why it isn't working.

Here is a screenshot of my Logcat Error's after my app crashes:

[image]

I have also checked the Verbose section to see if it just wasn't being recorded in Error's, but there is nothing related to a crash anywhere.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the "::" from the search bar?

Answer (score 1):

Check your search, I think you didn't clear it.

[image]

Comment: Jesus lol. Can't believe that was the issue. I restarted android studio multiple times, didn't realize past searches were saved. Thank you lmao